# using stubFor outside JUnit

Tags: java, junit, wiremock

`stubFor` is able to be used in JUnit without a WireMockServer instance, but it doesn't seem to work outside of JUnit:

```
final WireMockServer mockServer = new WireMockServer(options()
        .bindAddress("localhost")
        .port(9701));
mockServer.start();

stubFor(get(....));  // has runtime error (as follows)

mockServer.stubFor(get(....));  // must be called via a server instance
```

Is it possible to make the `stubFor` works outside of JUnit without specifying the server instance? I'm using wiremock both inside and outside of JUnit, would like to reuse similar logic.

-- EDIT --

This is the error when using `stubFor` without an instance. Looks like it's trying to connect to 8080 instead of 9701.

```
11:51:13.889 [restartedMain] WARN  o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase - The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [udp-nio-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.12/sun.nio.ch.KQueue.poll(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.12/sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:122)
 java.base@11.0.12/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:124)
 java.base@11.0.12/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:141)
 app//io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:68)
 app//io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:810)
 app//io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:457)
 app//io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
 app//io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@11.0.12/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
11:51:13.890 [restartedMain] WARN  o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase - The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [udp-nio-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.12/sun.nio.ch.KQueue.poll(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.12/sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:122)
 java.base@11.0.12/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:124)
 java.base@11.0.12/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:141)
 app//io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:68)
 app//io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:810)
 app//io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:457)
 app//io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
 app//io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 app//io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.base@11.0

...

11:51:13.912 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
11:51:13.934 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myMock' defined in file [/Users/my/target/classes/clients/myMock.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [myMock]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1316)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
```

Comment: What does "*has error*" mean? Do you get a compilation error? If so: please [edit] the post and add the compiler error. Does it throw an exception? If so: please [edit] the post and add the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out how to do it, need to use `configFor` to set the wiremock client.

First, extend the WireMockServe so we can get the client:

```
private static class MyMockServer extends WireMockServer {
    public MyMockServer(Options options) {
        super(options);
    }

    public WireMock getClient() {
        return client;
    }
}
```

Then, set the client:

```
final MyMockServer mockServer = new MyMockServer(options().port(9701));
configureFor(mockServer.getClient());
```

Now we can use `stubFor` directly without specifying the mockServer instance.